# Show a number to X place but drop 0?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm sure this is simple but if I need to display numbers dynamically using ASP.net (VB) like this:

1.5 => 1.5

2.0 => 2

1.25 => 1.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trim the zeros using [`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx):

```
string formatted = "2.0".TrimEnd(new char[] { '0', '.' });
```

Comment: Perfect!  Here is the code for vb people:

(1.0).ToString.TrimEnd(New Char() {"0", "."})